# Unity calendar lens not showing events

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, lenses, calendar, google-calendar

I'm trying to get proper/useful calendar integration into Ubuntu 12.04. I have a Google Calendar (& account) and I want to be able to use this without opening the browser.

I want to get the Unity Calendar lens working, so that it shows events coming up, and it allows me a quick way to add new events. However, after installing it, it does not find any events, nor allow me to add a new event.

Note that I've installed Lightning 1.4, Evolution mirror 0.2.3, Evolution, and unity-calendar lens. I've also installed Calendar-indicator.

I suspect that somehow the lens is not getting the calendar information from thunderbird via evolution.

A bit of searching around led me to try this command: `/usr/lib/calendar-lens/calendar-lens-daemon.py`. With this result:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
>     import gobject._gobject
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/calendar-lens/calendar-lens-daemon.py", line 324, in 
>       daemon = Daemon()
>     File "/usr/lib/calendar-lens/calendar-lens-daemon.py", line 80, in **init**
>       for calendar in evolution.ecal.list_calendars():
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'list_calendars'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had this setup running as expected in Ubuntu 11.10 (i.e. before you upgraded to 12.04)?  If not, have you actually run Evolution?

When Evolution first runs, it sets up the default calendars in its backend.  Until then, no calendars exist in Evolution.  This means that Evolution Mirror has no calendar to mirror Lightning's events to and also that the Calendar lens has no data source to get events from.

The error message you posted suggests that the lens is finding no calendars at all when it asks evolution for a list of them.

So, try running Evolution.  You don't need to set up any email accounts in it.  Then try adding an event in Lightning and see if it appears in the lens.  If this works, you'll also need to reset Evolution Mirror to resend all your existing events in Lightning to Evolution.  To do this:

1. In Thunderbird, go to **Edit** --> **Preferences** --> **Advanced** --> **Config Editor**
2. In the config editor, search for **evolution**.
3. Find the entry for **extensions.evolutionmirror.firstrun**.
4. Double click on the entry to change its value to **True**
5. Restart Thunderbird.  On restart, all your events will be copied into Evolution's database and subsequent updates to events in Lightning will be reflected in Evolution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Teester.
I had 10.04 before upgrading, so I didn't have unity running at all. Thus I'm still getting to grips with it!

I have run Evolution, but it doesn't seem to have any of my thunderbird calendars in it. Should they automatically be showing? Or is there some button in Evolution where I need to tell it to receive events from Lightning?

Comment: Just a note: I uninstalled and reinstalled Evolution Mirror, added an event in Thunderbird/Lightning. It doesn't show in the Lens, and doesn't show in the Evolution calendar.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is a missing dependency (python-gnome2).

`sudo apt-get install python-gnome2`

This should solve the issue.